# How can I find out which fonts are available in Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm working with python's turtle module and want to load different fonts. I've read that turtle uses tkinter's fonts but some of these fonts that should be available are in fact not. Does anyone know how I can add fonts or get a list of available ones? I would especially like to write arabic, hebrew fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to list fonts.

```py
import tkinter as tk
r = tk.Tk()
print(list(tk.font.families()))
```

Turtle is based on `tkinter`, so you list the `tkinter` fonts.

Answer (score 1):

1. To add a font, first download the font you want and install it on your system.
2. Then you can use this font in your code as shown in the example.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

turtle.write("Pacifico Font", align='center', font=('Pacifico', 48))

screen.mainloop()
```

I hope it helps you about adding a new font.

Reference: [How can I use custom local fonts in Python Turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614927/how-can-i-use-custom-local-fonts-in-python-turtle)

Also, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614027/list-available-font-families-in-tkinter) out too.

Comment: He asked how to get a list, not install one.

Comment: Still, thank you, your answer gave me a little more than needed but was helpful in any case :)